# Devexpress GridControl - refresh data in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress, gridcontrol

My grid:

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="StatisticsGridLevel1"
                 dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2013"
                 DataContext="{Binding FooViewModel}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding FooCollection}">
```

ViewModel:

```
private List<FooDto> fooCollection = new List<FooDto>();
public List<FooDto> FooCollection
{
    get
    {
        return this.fooCollection;
    }

    private set
    {
        this.fooCollection = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And example method:

```
private void Foo()
{
    foreach (var element in collection)
    {
        this.fooCollection.Add(new FooDto()
        {
            X = element.Foo1,
            Y = element.Foo2,
            Z = element.Foo3
        });
    }
    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FooCollection");
}
```

When I use ObservableCollection, everything works fine. But I want to use the List (that's not to notify in the loop).

The view refreshes after the start scroll on the grid. What is the problem?

Comment: Why can't you stick with `ObservableCollection`?  The grid is not going to update automatically when the collection is modified unless the collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  `ObservableCollection` implements that interface `List` does not.

Comment: Because I add to the collection a lot of items. I want to refresh the grid (manually invoke Notify) after finishing the loop.

Comment: Okay, so I get that but I don't really understand your question.  What does this mean: 'The view refreshes after the start scroll wheel on the grid'?  What is the start scroll wheel?  Are you referring to the mouse wheel?  Are you handling the mouse wheel event.  If so then that sounds like it may be pertinent to the question and you should show the code.  It sounds like you are saying the view is still refreshing in `Foo` despite the fact that you are using a `List` instead of an `ObservableCollection`?  Is that right?

Comment: No :) 

In the first step - I create List<FooDto> FooCollection with default values.

The values are displayed correctly in the grid.

In the second step - I call Update() method. Update cleaning collection and adding new items.

FooCollection.Clear();
FooCollection.Add(...) // Element 1
...
FooCollection.Add(...) // Element 50000
this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FooCollection");

Grid displays the old values. I click on the scroll in the grid (with old values) or click on the column (sort) - grid is already showing correct data.

Answer (score 0):

I think a `CollectionViewSource` would work in your case.  There are a lot of ways to go about creating one, in XAML, in your ViewModel, in your View's code-behind.  I will throw together the easiest one for demonstration purposes which is creating a `CollectionViewSource` property on your ViewModel.  I think some people might not necessarily like this approach - it kind of has the feel of mixing concerns.  I am not sure I agree, though.  If you take the position that a `CollectionViewSource` is an object model for a collection's view then I don't see anything wrong with having it in your ViewModel.  But I think because it inherits from `DependencyObject` it gets stigmatized as being more of a view concern.  Anyway, something like this would do what you want:

```
// Assuming this is your constructor
public ViewModel()
{
    this.FooViewSource.Source = this.fooCollection;
}

private readonly List<FooDto> fooCollection = new List<FooDto>();

private readonly CollectionViewSource fooViewSource;
public CollectionViewSource FooViewSource
{
    get { return this.fooViewSource; }
}

private void Foo()
{
    foreach (var element in collection)
    {
        this.fooCollection.Add(new FooDto()
        {
            X = element.Foo1,
            Y = element.Foo2,
            Z = element.Foo3
        });
    }
    this.FooViewSource.View.Refresh();
}
```

Then you would bind your `ItemsSource` property to the `FooViewSource` property of your ViewModel.  A `CollectionViewSource` is pretty handy for other things as well.  It supports sorting, filtering, selected items, maybe some other things I am forgetting.

Comment: Your solution fixes problems with performance. But DevExpress prevents sorting (sorting options when you click the right mouse button is grayed out). If not for this issue, this would be the perfect solution.

Comment: Is there an `AllowSorting` property on the `GridControl` that you can set to true?  See 'Sorting and Grouping' near the bottom of this link: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11124.

Comment: Alternatively, if the above does not work.  I would look for some sort of default view on the grid control.  I imagine there will be one and it more than likely has a function to refresh the view.  If that is the case I would add an event named something like `CollectionChanged` to the ViewModel and invoke it from within the `Foo` function anytime I changed the underlying list.  Then I would have the view subscribe to the event and call the grid's view's refresh method any time the event was fired.